# Find range subset combinations from main range in Excel via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Here are the particulars. Let's say you have a 10 X 10 range of cells- A1:J10 will work fine. What I'm trying to find via VBA is how many pairs of non intersecting ranges containing 5 cells and 4 cells can be derived from the main range of A1:J10. For example, A1:A5 (5 cell subset) and A6:A9 (4 cell subset) would be a valid pair. A1:E5 and A1:A4 would not be a valid pair due to the intersection of ranges at A1. I'm mostly just looking for the number of valid pairs, but if somebody can show how to physically list all the pairs on a worksheet as well that would help out.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Must each range be contiguous and rectangular?

Comment: So one range must contain 5 cells and the other one 4? Five has no factors apart from the obvious so can only be 1 X 5 or 5 X 1, 4 can be 1 X 4, 4 X 1 or 2 X 2. It shouldn't be too bad to work through those for your particular case, maybe quite a bit of code. A lot more difficult to do generally I think.

Comment: Must the range be totally filled with the sub-ranges? Or are you looking also for unfilled ranges?

Comment: Looking back, I made a typo in my example of what would not be a valid pair. Meant to use A1:A5 and A1:D1 as an example of an invalid pair. Not sure that matters, but I figured I'd clarify.

Comment: Tim- Yes. Tom - Yes. Evil Not sure what you're asking. I'm looking for how many pairs non intersecting 5 cell and 4 cell contiguous rectangular cell subranges exist given the main range of A1:J10. For example, I know there's 120 5 cell and 140 4 cell subranges. I just can't wrap my arms around taking the parameters and formulating an equation, etc. that will give me the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Range Subset Combinations

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub writeRangePairs()
    
    ' Source
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const srcRange = "A1:J10"
    Const RC1 As Long = 5
    Const RC2 As Long = 4
    ' Target
    Const tgtFirstCell As String = "L1"
    ' Other
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Define Source Range.
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range(srcRange)
        
    ' Write all possible range addresses
    ' to Source Arrays ('Source1', 'Source2').
    Dim Source1 As Variant
    Source1 = getOneRowOneCol(rng, RC1)
    Dim Source2 As Variant
    Source2 = getOneRowOneCol(rng, RC2)
    
    ' Define Target Array. It is too big,
    ' but It cannot be bigger than UB1 * UB2.
    Dim Target As Variant
    ReDim Target(1 To UBound(Source1) * UBound(Source2), 1 To 3)
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim m As Long
    
    ' Write values from Source Arrays to Target Array.
    For i = 1 To UBound(Source1)
        For k = 1 To UBound(Source2)
            If Intersect(ws.Range(Source1(i, 1)), ws.Range(Source2(k, 1))) _
              Is Nothing Then
                m = m + 1
                ' Write first range address.
                Target(m, 1) = Source1(i, 1)
                ' Write second range address.
                Target(m, 2) = Source2(k, 1)
                ' Write both addresses as one range address. This column
                ' will contain duplicates which could be removed
                ' by using a dictionary.
                Target(m, 3) = Union(ws.Range(Source1(i, 1)), _
                                     ws.Range(Source2(k, 1))).Address(0, 0)
            End If
        Next k
    Next i
    
    ' Write values from Target Array to Target Range. Since Target Array
    ' is too big, we are using 'm' instead of 'UBound(Target, 1)'.
    ws.Range(tgtFirstCell).Resize(m, UBound(Target, 2)).Value = Target
    
End Sub

Function getOneRowOneCol(SourceRange As Range, _
                         ByVal NumberOfCells As Long) _
         As Variant
    
    Dim r As Long
    r = SourceRange.Rows.Count
    Dim c As Long
    c = SourceRange.Columns.Count
    Dim NoRs As Long
    NoRs = r * (c - NumberOfCells + 1)
    Dim NoCs As Long
    NoCs = c * (r - NumberOfCells + 1)
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    ReDim Data(1 To NoRs + NoCs, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    
    ' Rows
    For i = 1 To r
        For j = 1 To c - NumberOfCells + 1
            Set rng = SourceRange.Cells(i, j).Resize(, NumberOfCells)
            k = k + 1
            Data(k, 1) = rng.Address(0, 0)
        Next j
    Next i
    
    ' Columns
    For j = 1 To c
        For i = 1 To r - NumberOfCells + 1
            Set rng = SourceRange.Cells(i, j).Resize(NumberOfCells)
            k = k + 1
            Data(k, 1) = rng.Address(0, 0)
        Next i
    Next j
    getOneRowOneCol = Data
    
'    Debug.Print UBound(Data)
'    For i = 1 To UBound(Data)
'        Debug.Print Data(i, 1)
'    Next i

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm!